# Syncing old iTunes to new iOS?

Tags: macos, itunes, ios

I have iTunes 10.6.1 installed on my Mac. My mac is version 10.6.7, and I cannot upgrade it because it is on an image with software update disabled. I just updated to iOS 6, and obviously can't downgrade. iTunes 10.7 is the first version of iTunes to support iOS 6, and iTunes 10.7 requires Mac 10.6.8. I have access to both Windows and Linux (unrestricted, unlike on the Mac), but my library is stored on an external HDD formated to HFS+ (OS X Extended), meaning it won't work with Windows (I believe the same problem would occur with a Windoes VM in Linux). iTunes doesn't support Linux, so I can't use it there. Is there some other way I could sync them?

Comment: Why are you locked in to 10.6.7? Also, if you backup your library, format the external HD as FAT, and restore the iTunes library to this FAT volume, you can use Windows with your library.

Comment: It's a long story why I'm locked into 10.6.7. For said long story, see http://pastebin.com/vsv2ggGz. My library is about 400GB on a 640GB external HDD. My Mac's internal HDD is 160GB. My windows/linux box has enough free space. That might be a last resort, but I think booting Linux and just copying from the HFS+ to the NTFS would be easier. Perhaps there's a utility that can mount an HFS+ drive? I've only found ones that can view files through their interface, but not make them accessible to other applications. I also thought of making an SMB server on my mac, but see the paste again.

Comment: For linux you can look into hfsprogs and hfsutils.

Comment: @duci9y Yes, but that would require a) iTunes to work on Linux, or b) My Windows and Linux box to be different computers so I could SMB my external drive to Windows from Linux.

Comment: You wanted something that can mount an HFS+ volume. hfsprogs and hfsutils allow you to do that.

Comment: @duci9y for Windows